# Why can't address elements be in p elements?

Tags: html, dom, seo, paragraph

I've reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542428/why-on-earth-is-address-a-block-level-element already and found that it adds little insight to the matter.

A client gave me a paragraph of plain text, and I'm attempting to optimize it for both user experience and SEO. Here's the relevant snippet, from the middle of the text:

```
<p>[Several sentences]. Having trouble? Contact <address style="font-style:normal;display:inline">Jane Doe at <a href="mailto:jdoe@example.com">jdoe@example.com</a> or <a href="callto:5551234567">(555) 123-4567</a></address> between the hours of 9AM and 5PM. [Several sentences].</p>
```

However, since `<address>` is a block-level element, the DOM ends up looking like this:

```
<p>[Several sentences]. Having trouble? Contact </p>
<address style="font-style:normal;display:inline">Jane Doe at <a href="mailto:jdoe@example.com">jdoe@example.com</a> or <a href="callto:5551234567">(555) 123-4567</a></address>
between the hours of 9AM and 5PM. [Several sentences].<p></p>
```

and the output looks like this:

> [Several sentences]. Having trouble? Contact
>
> Jane Doe at jdoe@example.com or (555) 123-4567
>
> between the hours of 9AM and 5PM. [Several sentences].

Obviously, this breaks the UX, and isn't valid HTML. My questions are **What is the reasoning behind `<address>` being block-level only, and is there any way I can make it display inline?** As you can see, the CSS `display:inline` attribute/value does nothing to help the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `<address>` element for generic addresses, instead use the [Person schema](http://schema.org/Person) with [Microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html), or the [hCard Microformat](http://www.microformats.org/wiki/hcard), or [RDFa](http://examples.tobyinkster.co.uk/hcard).  Here's a example with Microdata:

```
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    [Several sentences]. Having trouble? 
    Contact <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span> at 
    <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:jdoe@example.com">jdoe@example.com</a>
    or <a itemprop="telephone" href="tel:5551234567">(555) 123-4567</a> 
    between the hours of 9AM and 5PM.
    [Several sentences].
</p>
```

You can [test the data extraction with Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=&html=%3Cp+itemscope+itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%3E%0D%0A++++%5bSeveral+sentences%5d.+Having+trouble%3F+%0D%0A++++Contact+%3Cspan+itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJane+Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E+at+%0D%0A++++%3Ca+itemprop%3D%22email%22+href%3D%22mailto%3Ajdoe%40example.com%22%3Ejdoe%40example.com%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A++++or+%3Ca+itemprop%3D%22telephone%22+href%3D%22tel%3A5551234567%22%3E%28555%29+123-4567%3C%2Fa%3E+%0D%0A++++between+the+hours+of+9AM+and+5PM.%0D%0A++++%5bSeveral+sentences%5d.%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E) (scroll down to the section titled 'Extracted structured data').

Comment: Can you provide code that will work as an alternate solution?

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't address elements be in `p` elements?

[Because the HTML specification defines them that way](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-address-element).

> The `address` element represents the contact information for its nearest `article` or `body` element ancestor. If that is the `body` element, then the contact information applies to the document as a whole.

What this means is that `<address>` elements aren't meant to be used to mark up any old address. The implication is that you'd be using the `<address>` as a means of contacting the source of the article. Within an article, discussing "123 fourth street" would not merit using an `<address>` element.

If you want to describe it as an address for styling purposes, you could always give it a `class` as:

```
<span class="address">123 fourth street</span>
```

Comment: I wanted to optimize it for SEO, and the client (the contact for the article) wants her address to be provided within a paragraph.

Comment: @Supuhstar, then it should be `<address><p>Having trouble? Contact Jane Doe at <a...>jdoe@example.com</a> or <a...>123123123</a> between the hours of 9AM and 5PM.</p></address>`.

Comment: @zzzzBov It says in the spec you linked to: "The address element must not contain information other than contact information."

Comment: @robertc, and the example I provided *was* contact information. The spec was talking more generally about types of content that are not at all related to contact information. Yes, technically, the "Having trouble?" question isn't contact information, but it's relevant to the content flow of the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: @zzzzBov I would say "Having trouble?" is *not* contact information.  But the spec is ambiguous I think.

Comment: @zzzzBov Don't forget that there are several sentences before and after the "Having trouble?" section that I gave.

Comment: @Supuhstar, then the simple solution is to *not* put it in an `address` element. For SEO you can use [schema](http://schema.org) as robertc mentioned.

Comment: @robertc: I'd say "Having trouble?" can be considered part of the contact information here, as it tells the user about desirable subjects/topics of contacting the author.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I think you should include the alternative (from your first comment) in your answer.